# Error when converting .py file to exe

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, exe, cx-freeze

I'm getting this error in command prompt when I try to covert my .py file into an exe:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tcl8.6'`

Here's my setup.py file code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup (name = 'CODAQ Beta', version = '0.1', description = 'Aerosol Data Visualization Environment', executables = [Executable("CODAQ.py")])
```

I've heard that may I have to change `os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY']` and `os.environ['TK_LIBRARY']` depending on the path of `tcl8.6` and `tk.86` in my system. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Is `tcl8.6` in `C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

tcl was actually in Anaconda3:

here's the code I changed:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup (name = 'CODAQ Beta', version = '0.1', description = 'Aerosol Data Visualization Environment', executables = [Executable("CODAQ.py")])
```